# What does 'community wiki' mean?

Tags: discussion

This question explains the *Community Wiki* feature and when it should be used.

Answer (score 1):

**Why do *Community Wiki* posts exist?**

To assist in making [SharePointOverflow](http://www.sharepointoverflow.com) an evolving source of quality information, by enhancing the wiki aspect of the site.

**How do *Community Wiki* posts work?**

- They are owned by the Community user, not by the original poster (OP).
- They can be edited by people with a lower reputation score than non-community posts.
- No reputation can be gained or lost on community posts. Badges can still be awarded to the original poster.
- The original author keeps any reputation gained or lost before the post entered community mode.
- Once a question has entered community mode, all of its answers are also changed to community wiki.

**How does a post become *Community Wiki*?**

When:

- The post's author selects the "Community Wiki" check box while adding or editing a post.
- The post has been edited several times by the original owner.
- The post has been edited by several different people.
- Many answers are given for a question.

**When should a *question* be *Community Wiki*?**

- If it is about this site, SharePointOverflow. This helps to focus attention on contributing SharePoint content to the site, not meta content.
- If it is a poll or list of resources. This reduces reputation harvesting and encourages people to vote freely for answers that are not their own. You should also request one item per answer so that it is easy for votes to sort the list by popularity.
- If you know when posting the question that there isn't really an answer.

**When should an *answer* be *Community Wiki*?**

- If you'd like your answer to be further fleshed out by others, or if you would like to combine other people's answers together into yours.

**Can a post be changed from *Community Wiki* to normal?**

No. The only way to do this is delete and repost.

Comment: This should probably be heavily updated, if we don't have a proper Community Wiki post for the new system.